# EF webgrid RANK function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ranking, webgrid

I have a problem where my grid is showing zero's but they should be displaying the appropriate RANK() from the SQL result.

I've attached generic info about my problem... having no luck , tried format ("#,####") etc and data type casting.

```
    @{
            WebGrid grid4 = new WebGrid(ViewBag.Customers);
        }
        @grid4.GetHtml(
        tableStyle: "gridTable",
        headerStyle: "gridHead",
        footerStyle: "gridFooter",
        rowStyle: "gridRow",
            alternatingRowStyle: "gridRow",
            //alternatingRowStyle: "gridAltRow",
            columns: grid4.Columns(
                grid4.Column("AcctID", "Code", format: (item) => item.AcctCode),
                grid4.Column("CustName", "Customer Name", format: (item) => item.CustName.ToString()),  
                grid4.Column("LossRank", "Loss Rank", format: (item) => item.LossRank.ToString("#,###,###,##0"))
               //TODO: Revisit this one and fix or find substitute for LossRank
               )
        )
```

[image: Just a pic I have drawn up]

Comment: You are passing in the item as the format...

Comment: Show the WebGrid code and its corresponding action

Comment: Edited, please let me know if you need further info.

Comment: ` @using (Ajax.BeginForm("ViewDashboard", "Dashboard", new AjaxOptions
{
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "gridarea",
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    OnFailure = "OnFailure",
    OnSuccess = "OnSuccess"
}
                                                                                                                , new { id = "Ajaxform" }))
{
     @Html.Partial("sales_corporate/_grid1", TempData["CORP_OBSHIP"], new ViewDataDictionary { { "viewName", "_sales_corporate_grid1" } }) } `